# Error : "Please fix the following errors: Invite code is invalid."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am trying to integrate spree_hub_connector gem with my Spree application.
Followed Step by Step instructions as described in below link :

http://guides.spreecommerce.com/integration/configuration.html

Encountered Error : "Please fix the following errors: Invite code is invalid."
in official guideline, nothing is mentioned about "invite code".
[image]

I am using stable 2-1-stable version for both spree & spree_hub_connector.

Git link for my sample Project: 
https://github.com/AjayROR/spree_hub_connector_sample_example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spree Hub is a commercial product. If you're an existing customer, please email support@spreecommerce.com and the team will get you set up. Otherwise, you can get more information by using the "Contact Us" option on http://spreecommerce.com/product/hub or by emailing sales@spreecommerce.com.

Comment: What if they are just using https://github.com/spree/spree ? Being a commercial product is cool, but directing people to your sales folks when using an open source product isn't cool.

Comment: Noah,

The Spree storefront is open source, but that's not where he is running into an issue. He's having an issue with the Hub connector, which is the open source code used to connect to the commercial product. 

His issue will only be resolved by talking to sales, as that is the only way to get an invite code.

Comment: Answer seems reasonable !
Will check with spree Support Team.